# How sensitive are the DVI sync signals?

Tags: video, monitor, video-transmitter

We're trying to output a full mono-colored screen signal in 640x480 resolution over DVI to a Samsung monitor from an FPGA board. The problem we have is that we don't get any picture showing, instead the monitor show a small grey box with the text "Not optimum mode mode\nRecommended mode\n1920x1200". From this point we find it very difficult to troubleshoot.

Perhaps the sync signals is a bit of? Or the amount of pixel data sent is wrong?

What are the requirements on the H-sync and V-sync? Do they need to be active for a long period of time? Is this time very exact or will the picture show if the syncs a few clock cycles too long or too short?

Should H-sync be active during the V-sync? No we have two H-syncs during the duration of the V-sync. Does it sound ok?

What happens if we just send 639 pixels per line or as many as 641? Will the picture show?

Comment: _"Perhaps the sync signals is a bit of?"_ What did your eye-diagram measurement show?

Comment: Is this monitor actually willing to display 640x480 at all, e.g. from a PC?

Comment: Are your sync polarities correct?

Comment: As @pjc50 says, check your monitors supported resolutions. Not all monitors will support all standard resolutions.

Comment: @DonFusili Yes, the sync signals are configured to be active low.

Comment: Are your front and back porch timings correct? There is some detail here http://tinyvga.com/vga-timing/640x480@60Hz

Comment: Thanks for all the hints. We actually solved outputting of 640x480 just now, feels great! The problem was that we forgot we only send out half a pixel each cycle which means we sent 320 pixels per line instead of 640 ...

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the commenters I doubt that monitors would have trouble supporting the standard 640x480 VGA resolution, as the DVI standard actually mandates support for a so-called "low pixel format" which is 640 × 480 at 60 Hz. Monitors with no analog input (i.e. no VGA input) will probably be equipped with a DVI-D interface (which doesn't accept a DVI-I nor DVI-A connector).

My guess is that since pin 8 is used by digital inputs as well, you could try sending an analog vertical synchronization signal at that pin (its timing should probably match to the timing of the digital sync signals though).

The other thing which needs to be watched out for is the minimum clock frequency of 25.175 MHz mandated by the DVI standard. Anything below that will surely be rejected by the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Sending too many pixels is ok, sending too few pixels is also ok. Moving the non-blanking period (where data-enable is high) during the active time (changing how long the back-porch and front-porch times are) also seems to be fine.

But the problem is the total time. Just having the total amount of cycles per line off by one will render NO image at all. I'm guessing the total time to send the frame is too fast or too slow.